# SqlParameter is not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

. I am having trouble getting the `SqlParameter` to work on my `SqlCommand`. When I run the code below the SqlParameters do not get applied to the SqlCommand.

```
SqlCommand tSQL = new SqlCommand();
tSQL.CommandText = "SELECT TraceEvent.name AS [EventName], Trace.* FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), (@filepath)), @numberoffiles) Trace JOIN sys.trace_events TraceEvent ON Trace.EventClass = TraceEvent.trace_event_id WHERE TraceEvent.name LIKE @eventType ORDER BY Trace.StartTime";

tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("filepath", @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_11.trc");
tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("numberoffiles", 1);
tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("eventType", '%');

tSQL.Connection = Connection;

Connection.Open();
Connection.ChangeDatabase("master");

DataSet DataSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(tSQL);

Adapter.Fill(DataSet);

foreach (DataTable Table in DataSet.Tables)
{
    Result.Add(Table);
}
```

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: the sqlparameters do not get applied

Comment: change @ to ? and try

Comment: nope the ? didn't work. thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Two things as I observe  tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberoffiles", 1);. Do observe @ add it to all add with value methods. 2)Dataset dataset=new Dataset();make necessary changes throughout the program

Comment: "This code doesn't work" is not a helpful problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U Have missed '@' before the sql parameters..

```
tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filepath", @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\log_11.trc");
tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberoffiles", 1);
tSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventType", '%');
```

I guess this will help..